# Lua make table readonly

Tags: c#, security, scripting, lua, sandbox

How do I make a table read-only in Lua? (specifically, LuaInterface with Lua 5.1 for C#, but I don't think that will change anything)
I know how to use `__index` and `__newindex`, but that doesn't prevent someone from running:
`math = nil`, which could potentially cause further scripts to incorrectly execute.

My current "protect" function:

```
function protect(table) 
return setmetatable({}, { __index = table, 
__newindex = function(table, key, value) error("attempted to modify a read only table")         
end, __metatable = false }) end

math = protect(math)
math.sqrt = nil // successfully protected
math = nil // this is bad and can happen!
```

Comment: You didn't mention what Lua version you're using. It's relevant in this case.

Comment: i have updated the original post

Answer (score 5):

The global environment is just a table. In Lua 5.1, every function (which is what a compiled Lua script is) has its own environment, which you can *change*. If you want to sandbox scripts so that they can't modify the global table, you can do so by *replacing* their environment with a sandboxed one.

Basically, you create a read-only table that you put the stuff you want them to be able to access into. You can even set up your metatable so that it prevents overwriting existing elements, but allows them to modify entries that don't currently exist (ie: they can create and use their own globals).

That being said, unless you remove the ability for the user to `rawget`/`rawset`, they can always back-door your sandbox and start breaking these tables.

A more secure version is to build an environment for each script by copying functions around. Rather than every script getting the same `math` table, they get copies of the original which you have squirreled away in places that scripts can't touch.

Comment: my current sandbox code is actually like this:
http://pastebin.com/1kzCGztL (ignore the usage of tags; it didn't compile)

I have a "LuaManager", which runs scripts by calling LuaManager.RunFile("filename")

How would I hide the global variables in this case?  Would setfenv work?